# Acrobat wont collate pages when printing so they come out in the wrong order

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Ive got some line weight heavy graphics files that slow down Mac's inbuilt preview app when viewed.

So recently I've switched to Acrobat Pro as my default PDF viewer. Only issue is with multi page PDFs it doesn't seem to collate them when printing like Mac Preview does, so it ends up printing the page 1 first which means if i have a ten page document i then have to re shuffle the paper out of the printer.

Any ideas how i can set Acrobat to automatically print the last page first ?

Version wise im running the latest version of Acrobat (on subscription through creative cloud) on a Mac running 10.10.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Acrobat's Print dialog....

Click the `More Options` arrow to expand that area....

Then tick the `Reverse Pages` option. The PDF will print in reverse order.

[image]

<sub>Screenshot from Acrobat Pro X, because I dislike all newer versions. However, the option to reverse should be present in all versions, it may just appear in a different location.</sub>